# saga_cmd - process never ends

Tags: saga, grids-graticules, debian, saga-cmd, gridding

I am trying to use saga_cmd with the debian 11 (package v7.3.0) to create an interpolation process.

With Qgis, the process take around 1 minute and works fine, but the process seems never ends with the linux package and show `100%interpolating` :

```
identifier  : 3
author      : O.Conrad (c) 2008
processors  : 8 [8]
____________________________

Load shapes: 20050701.shp...

100%okay


Parameters


Points: 20050701
Attribute: z
Target Grid System: user defined
Cellsize: 0.500000
West: 151374.300000
East: 152552.300000
South: 6862795.800000
North: 6863927.300000
Columns: 2357
Rows: 2264
Fit: nodes
Method: Sibson
Minimum Weight: 0.000000


100%interpolating
```

Here the command line :

```
saga_cmd grid_gridding "Natural Neighbour" -TARGET_DEFINITION 0 -POINTS "20050701.shp" -FIELD "z" -TARGET_USER_SIZE 0.5 -METHOD 1 -WEIGHT 0.0 -TARGET_OUT_GRID "20050701_OUT_GRID.sdat"
```

Does anyone know about this behaviour ?

Comment: In addition, if i use script shell with linux i get the same result. But the same command under windows (as .bat) works fine ! 
Under linux, i can use other saga_cmd algo (e.g convert csv to table).
Why this script don't works with linux ?